# How to Play VK Videos on Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, vk

I've been developing an android project that will show videos from vk.com

I tried like that code but doesnt work..

```
 String summary = "<html><body>
  <iframe src='http://vk.com/video_ext.php?
  oid=212385333&id=165112002&hash=6bb837b4953f5f10&hd=1' 
  width='607' height='360' frameborder='0'></iframe></body></html>";
    webView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

I can show thumnail but it doent play..

I dont want to use API because it needs api key, confirmation for users.. blabla .. Is there anyway to play a video on webview without authorisation ?

I just want to play videos with VK Embed codes.. Is is possible, if its not, what are another alternatives?

Comment: "Blah blah" - in other words, please help me to violate the terms and conditions of this network - http://vk.com/terms

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you have this:

```
<application
...
android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
```

set in your AndroidManifest.xml

2) Try setting a WebChromeClient for your WebView:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

mVideoView.setVideoPath("http://188.138.51.133/qq/1/22/toyota_etios_liva_video_reg_53714.3gp");
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```